# Upload CSV and insert related data

Tags: apex

I am trying to upload a CSV file from a Visualforce page and have it insert data into 2 custom objects, one object called "Candidate" the other "CandidateCertifications"  The data for both objects is in a single row in the CSV file.

The code here reads the csv file and inserts the candidate records, but I am struggling on how to iterate over candidate the records after they are inserted because I need the newly inserted IDs to relate the CandidateCertification records AND access to the array values in the CSV, but can't figure how to mesh the need to loop and read the CSV data.

```
public string csvFile{get;set;}
public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
String[] filelines = new String[]{};
List<Candidate__c> candidatesToUpload= new List<Candidate__c>();

public Pagereference ReadFile() {

    csvFile=blobToString( contentFile,'ISO-8859-1');
    filelines = csvFile.split('\n');

    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++) {
      String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
      inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

      Candidate__c newCandidate = new Candidate__c();
      newCandidate.FirstName = inputValues[0];
      newCandidate.LastName = inputValues[1];
      newCandidate.Email = inputValues[2];

      candidatesToUpload.add(newCandidate);
    }

    insert candidatesToUpload;

    // psuedo code that doesn't work - loop over our new candidate records so we can get the new Ids
    for( Candidate__c cand : candidatesToUpload) {
        ....  
        CandidateCertification__c newCert = new CandidateCertification__c;
        newCandidateCert.certDate = inputValues[3];
        newCandidateCert.certTitle = inputValues[4];
        newCandidateCert.Candidate = cand.Id
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure when we are inserting a list. But when a insert a single row, the ID is populated after the insert. Do you test it? Really the ID is returning null?

Answer (score 1):

As m Peixotot commented, the Id value of records that have been inserted is automatically made available back in Apex for this very purpose.

So you can make a second pass over the CSV data, grabbing the parent object Id like this:

```
List<CandidateCertification__c> certsToUpload= new List<CandidateCertification__c>();
for (Integer i = 1; i < filelines.size(); i++) {
    String[] inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
    Candidate__c cand = candidatesToUpload[i - 1];
    certsToUpload.add(new CandidateCertification__c(
        Candidate__c = cand.Id,
        CertDate__c = inputValues[3],
        CertTitle__c = inputValues[4],
        ...
    ));
}
insert certsToUpload;
```

Note the useful feature of SObjects that you can supply named constructor arguments and so make the code a little cleaner.

Also, unless you need values to be available across more than one method, put the declaration of the value inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in the csv acts as a single candidate record. In order to link `Candidate__c` record with `CandidateCertification__c`, you could iterate the same csv and use the list of inserted candidates to fetch the ID to link it together.

```
public string csvFile{get;set;}
public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
String[] filelines = new String[]{};
List<Candidate__c> candidatesToUpload= new List<Candidate__c>();

public Pagereference ReadFile() {

    csvFile=blobToString( contentFile,'ISO-8859-1');
    filelines = csvFile.split('\n');

    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++) {
      String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
      inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

      Candidate__c newCandidate = new Candidate__c();
      newCandidate.FirstName = inputValues[0];
      newCandidate.LastName = inputValues[1];
      newCandidate.Email = inputValues[2];

      candidatesToUpload.add(newCandidate);
    }

    insert candidatesToUpload;

    List<CandidateCertification__c> candidateCertificationList = new List<CandidateCertification__c>();
    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++) {
      String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
      inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
      CandidateCertification__c newCandidateCert= new CandidateCertification__c;
      newCandidateCert.certDate = inputValues[3];
      newCandidateCert.certTitle = inputValues[4];
      newCandidateCert.Candidate = candidatesToUpload.get(i-1).Id;
      candidateCertificationList.add(newCandidateCert);
    }
    insert candidateCertificationList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you.

Using map is the bast way.

```
map<Integer,list<Candidate__c >> candidateMap = new map<Integer,list<Candidate__c>>();
map< Integer,list< CandidateCertification__c  >> certificateMap = new map< Integer,list< CandidateCertification__c >>();
list<Candidate__c> candidateList = new list<Candidate__c>();
list<CandidateCertification__c> certificateList = new list<CandidateCertification__c>();

for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++) {
     String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
     inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

     Candidate__c newCandidate = new Candidate__c();
     newCandidate.FirstName = inputValues[0];
     newCandidate.LastName = inputValues[1];
     newCandidate.Email = inputValues[2];
     candidateList.add(newCandidate);

     CandidateCertification__c newCandidateCert= new CandidateCertification__c;
     newCandidateCert.certDate = inputValues[3];
     newCandidateCert.certTitle = inputValues[4];
     certificateList.add(newCandidateCert);
     candidateMap.put(i,candidateList);
     certificateMap.put(i,certificateList);
 }

 insert candidateMap.values();

 list<CandidateCertification__c> certificateToInsert = new list<CandidateCertification__c>();
 for(string s : certificateMap.keySet()){
     Candidate__c cand = certificateMap.get(s);
     for(CandidateCertification__c cert : certificateMap.get(s)){
         cert.Candidate  = cand.Id;
         certificateToInsert.add(cert);
     }
 }

 insert certificateToInsert;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's of limited value because it's largely a _code dump_. This answer would be improved if you were to spend time explaining _how_ this addresses the problem at hand. Doing so may allow OP, or other people visiting this question with similar (but not identical) issues to make small adjustments (in case you made a mistake, or someone's requirements are slightly different).